# Sqoop --password-file give bad substitution error

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am new to hadoop, trying to run following sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vaibhav --table employees --username root --password-file ${user.home}/.password.txt --target-dir /data/sqoop/eg4/ -m 2
```

but it gives me an error as

> bash: ${user.home}/.password.txt: bad substitution

I tried the way it is given in the docs, but nothing happened. same error every time.
Step by step guide would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: location of the password.txt file and use that location in place of ${user.home}/.password.txt

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I did so, but it says file not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop expects the password file on HDFS location. Try copying the file to a location on HDFS and specify that path. Also check the read permission of the file. Read permission should be to given to home directory user.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, there was a read permission problem for the home directory user.